# How to encode audio once for multiple output videos with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I would like to create several output videos with different resolutions but the same audio. Afaik audio encoding is an output option.

```
ffmpeg \
  -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv \
  -i <input> \
  -filter_complex '[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=stereo,aresample=async=1,asplit=3[a1][a2][a3];[0:v]vpp_qsv=detail=50:framerate=25,split=3[v1][v2][v3];[v2]vpp_qsv=width=1280[v2o];[v3]vpp_qsv=width=800[v3o]' \
  -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac -b:a 96k -map '[v1]'  -map '[a1]' <output> \
  -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac -b:a 96k -map '[v2o]' -map '[a2]' <output> \
  -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac -b:a 96k -map '[v3o]' -map '[a3]' <output>
```

Above I have two redundant audio encodings.

How can I encode the audio just once and copy it for the different outputs?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee):

```
ffmpeg \
  -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i <input> \
  -filter_complex '[0:a]aformat=channel_layouts=stereo,aresample=async=1[a];[0:v]vpp_qsv=detail=50:framerate=25,split=3[v1][v2][v3];[v2]vpp_qsv=width=1280[v2o];[v3]vpp_qsv=width=800[v3o]' \
  -map '[v1]' -map '[v2o]' -map '[v3o]' -map '[a]' \
  -c:v h264_qsv -c:a aac -b:a 96k -f tee -flags +global_header \
  "[select=\'v:0,a\']output.mkv|[select=\'v:1,a\':f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://server0/app/instance/playpath|[select=\'v:2,a\':movflags=+faststart]output.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround with some overhead for muxing and de-muxing but savings in the long run:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> \
  -af 'aformat=channel_layouts=stereo,aresample=async=1' \
  -c:a libopus -b:a 64k -ar 48k \
  -c:v copy       \
  -f mpegts - |   \
ffmpeg \
  -hwaccel qsv -c:v h264_qsv \
  -f mpegts -i -             \
  -filter_complex '[0:v]vpp_qsv=detail=50:framerate=25,split=3[v][v2][v3];[v2]vpp_qsv=width=1280[720p];[v3]vpp_qsv=width=800[450p]'  \
  -map '[v]'    -map 0:a -c:v h264_qsv -c:a copy <output> \
  -map '[720p]' -map 0:a -c:v h264_qsv -c:a copy <output> \
  -map '[450p]' -map 0:a -c:v h264_qsv -c:a copy <output>
```